# How do I fix this Array Index out of Bounds Exception?

Tags: java, serversocket

I am trying to study a multi-client chat server. As i'm new in Java, I am unable to run this two .java files in Net beans. I have two java projects and put I these files under them. Server project runs successfully but client project shows:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
at chatClient.main(chatClient.java:73)
```

**Client Project**

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;

class chatClient extends Frame implements Runnable {

    Socket soc;
    TextField tf;
    TextArea ta;
    Button btnSend, btnClose;
    String sendTo;
    String LoginName;
    Thread t = null;
    DataOutputStream dout;
    DataInputStream din;

    chatClient(String LoginName, String chatwith) throws Exception {
        super(LoginName);
        this.LoginName = LoginName;
        sendTo = chatwith;
        tf = new TextField(50);
        ta = new TextArea(50, 50);
        btnSend = new Button("Send");
        btnClose = new Button("Close");
        soc = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 5217);

        din = new DataInputStream(soc.getInputStream());
        dout = new DataOutputStream(soc.getOutputStream());
        dout.writeUTF(LoginName);

        t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();

    }

    void setup() {
        setSize(600, 400);
        setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));

        add(ta);
        Panel p = new Panel();

        p.add(tf);
        p.add(btnSend);
        p.add(btnClose);
        add(p);
        show();
    }

    public boolean action(Event e, Object o) {
        if (e.arg.equals("Send")) {
            try {
                dout.writeUTF(sendTo + " " + "DATA" + " " + tf.getText().toString());
                ta.append("\n" + LoginName + " Says:" + tf.getText().toString());
                tf.setText("");
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }
        } else if (e.arg.equals("Close")) {
            try {
                dout.writeUTF(LoginName + " LOGOUT");
                System.exit(1);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }

        }

        return super.action(e, o);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        chatClient Client1 = new chatClient(args[0],args[1]);
        Client1.setup();
    }

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                ta.append("\n" + sendTo + " Says :" + din.readUTF());

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Server Project**

```
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class chatServer {

    static Vector ClientSockets;
    static Vector LoginNames;

    chatServer() throws Exception {
        ServerSocket soc = new ServerSocket(5217);
        ClientSockets = new Vector();
        LoginNames = new Vector();

        while (true) {
            Socket CSoc = soc.accept();
            AcceptClient obClient = new AcceptClient(CSoc);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        chatServer ob = new chatServer();
    }

    class AcceptClient extends Thread {

        Socket ClientSocket;
        DataInputStream din;
        DataOutputStream dout;

        AcceptClient(Socket CSoc) throws Exception {
            ClientSocket = CSoc;

            din = new DataInputStream(ClientSocket.getInputStream());
            dout = new DataOutputStream(ClientSocket.getOutputStream());

            String LoginName = din.readUTF();

            System.out.println("User Logged In :" + LoginName);
            LoginNames.add(LoginName);
            ClientSockets.add(ClientSocket);
            start();
        }

        public void run() {
            while (true) {

                try {
                    String msgFromClient = new String();
                    msgFromClient = din.readUTF();
                    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(msgFromClient);
                    String Sendto = st.nextToken();
                    String MsgType = st.nextToken();
                    int iCount = 0;

                    if (MsgType.equals("LOGOUT")) {
                        for (iCount = 0; iCount < LoginNames.size(); iCount++) {
                            if (LoginNames.elementAt(iCount).equals(Sendto)) {
                                LoginNames.removeElementAt(iCount);
                                ClientSockets.removeElementAt(iCount);
                                System.out.println("User " + Sendto + " Logged Out ...");
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                    } else {
                        String msg = "";
                        while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                            msg = msg + " " + st.nextToken();
                        }
                        for (iCount = 0; iCount < LoginNames.size(); iCount++) {
                            if (LoginNames.elementAt(iCount).equals(Sendto)) {
                                Socket tSoc = (Socket) ClientSockets.elementAt(iCount);
                                DataOutputStream tdout = new DataOutputStream(tSoc.getOutputStream());
                                tdout.writeUTF(msg);
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        if (iCount == LoginNames.size()) {
                            dout.writeUTF("I am offline");
                        } else {

                        }
                    }
                    if (MsgType.equals("LOGOUT")) {
                        break;
                    }

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably don't specify any arguments `args[0],args[1]` so you get the exception because `args` is empty.

Comment: as @t3chb0t noted, you might want to check `args.length` before trying to read from it.

Comment: Which line is line `73` in `chatClient`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at your client's constructor you'll see that it requires two arguments:

```
chatClient(String LoginName, String chatwith)
```

a login and with whom to chat.

I think you don't specify them so the following line throws an exception because there aren't any and `args` is empty:

```
chatClient Client1 = new chatClient(args[0],args[1]);
```

Comment: You also might want to read something about [Using Command Line Arguments in NetBeans IDE](http://netbeanside61.blogspot.de/2009/02/using-command-line-arguments-in.html)

Answer (score 0):

The java arguments you pass from the command line are actually an array of String. If you do not type anything into the command line (or the NetBeans equivalent you will get an ArrrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. Therefore you get an exception because you try to pass an array of strings into chatClient method without there actually being any arguments.